# Need example of how to pass Specflow's ScenarioContext stored value to API request body in C#

Tags: c#, json, request, parameter-passing, specflow

I'm using .NET Core, Specflow, Selenium and JSON for API testing. I'm passing a stored value into my request body using Specflow's ScenarioContext. The error I receive is "'{salesOrderType}' cannot be found in the system". Can someone provide an example of how to pass my salesOrderType value to the request body in C#?

**Here's my stored values:**

```
var salesOrderNumber = _scenarioContext["SalesOrderNumber"];
var salesOrderType = _scenarioContext["SalesOrderType"];
```

**Here's my request body:**

```
var body = @"{

" + "\n" +

            @"    ""entity"": {

" + "\n" +

            @"        ""OrderType"": {

" + "\n" +

            $@"            ""value"": ""{salesOrderType}""

" + "\n" +

            @"        },

" + "\n" +

            @"        ""OrderNbr"": {

" + "\n" +

            $@"            ""value"": ""{salesOrderNumber}""

" + "\n" +

            @"        }

" + "\n" +

            @"    }

" + "\n" +

            @"}";
```

Comment: You do not pass the type.  When you send a request you are using json serialization to take class data and convert to json.  When server receives request a deserialization occurs.  So the class has to be defined in both client and server.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I have C# code that successfully executes a request. The only difference, between that code and the code I’m working on now, is that the body doesn’t have a stored value in it. That’s what I need to figure out - what’s the C# syntax to pass a stored value into the request body?

Comment: It is a variable?  The body you have is a string and modifying should be the same as any other string.  It is is a variable you just use the variable name without double quotes.

Comment: Yes, it's a variable. When I remove the double quotes from the variable name, I get this error for the response content:

{"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"entity.OrderType.value":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: W. Path 'entity.OrderType.value', line 7, position 21.","Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: W. Path 'entity.OrderType.value', line 7, position 21."]}}

Comment: I do not see modelState in the body.  Check you database tables/columns and compare to the Entity Model.  The Entity Model may not be in sync with the Database.  You may need to refresh the model.

Comment: Go back to your leader.  Tell him it is an entity error.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue as I’m running a similar test that passes successfully in Postman

Comment: Postman you are not using entity.  Entity is the c# classes that may the database to the c# classes.  When connecting from entity there is a serialization that occurs with classes to create the json.  When you are using Postman there is no serialization.  You are just putting data into a body of a request.  Can you compare the Postman Request with the c# request?

Comment: It turns out my code works fine in Dev but not QA, so it has nothing to do with my code but the environment.

Comment: Don't understand you last comment.  Postman uses different default HTTP Headers and sometimes issues like this are due to the headers need changes in c#.  Other times proxy is enabled in c# and not in postman.  And sometimes it is TLS that is failing.  Postman may be using for TLS OPENSSL which c# is using the OS.  All this could be what you are description as the environment.